# How does std::tie work?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I've used `std::tie` without giving much thought into it. It works so I've just accepted that:

```
auto test()
{
   int a, b;
   std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(2, 3);
   // a is now 2, b is now 3
   return a + b; // 5
}
```

But how does this *black magic* work? How does a temporary created by `std::tie` change `a` and `b`? I find this more interesting since it's a library feature, not a language feature, so surely it is something we can implement ourselves and understand.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

In order to clarify the core concept, let's reduce it to a more basic example. Although `std::tie` is useful for functions returning (a tuple of) more values, we can understand it just fine with just one value:

```
int a;
std::tie(a) = std::make_tuple(24);
return a; // 24
```

Things we need to know in order to go forward:

- `std::tie` constructs and returns a tuple of references.
- `std::tuple<int>` and `std::tuple<int&>` are 2 completely different classes, with no connection between them, other that they were generated from the same template, `std::tuple`.
- tuple has an `operator=` accepting a tuple of different types (but same number), where each member is assigned individually—from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D):

  > ```
  > template< class... UTypes >
  > tuple& operator=( const tuple<UTypes...>& other );
  > ```
  >
  > (3) For all i, assigns `std::get<i>(other)` to `std::get<i>(*this)`.

The next step is to get rid of those functions that only get in your way, so we can transform our code to this:

```
int a;
std::tuple<int&>{a} = std::tuple<int>{24};
return a; // 24
```

The next step is to see exactly what happens inside those structures.
For this, I create 2 types `T` substituent for `std::tuple<int>` and `Tr` substituent `std::tuple<int&>`, stripped down to the bare minimum for our operations:

```
struct T { // substituent for std::tuple<int>
    int x;
};

struct Tr { // substituent for std::tuple<int&>
    int& xr;

    auto operator=(const T& other)
    {
       // std::get<I>(*this) = std::get<I>(other);
       xr = other.x;
    }
};

auto foo()
{
    int a;
    Tr{a} = T{24};

    return a; // 24
}
```

And finally, I like to get rid of the structures all together (well, it's not 100% equivalent, but it's close enough for us, and explicit enough to allow it):

```
auto foo()
{
    int a;

    { // block substituent for temporary variables

    // Tr{a}
    int& tr_xr = a;

    // T{24}
    int t_x = 24;

    // = (asignement)
    tr_xr = t_x;
    }

    return a; // 24
}
```

So basically, `std::tie(a)` initializes a data member reference to `a`. `std::tuple<int>(24)` creates a data member with value `24`, and the assignment assigns 24 to the data member reference in the first structure. But since that data member is a reference bound to `a`, that basically assigns `24` to `a`.

Comment: What bugs me is that there is that we're calling the assignment operator to an rvalue.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010943/661935) answer, it stated that a container can't hold a reference. Why `tuple` could hold a reference?

Comment: @nn0p `std::tuple` is not a container, at least not in the C++ terminology, not the same as the `std::vector` and the likes. For instance you can't iterate with the usual ways over a tuple because it contains different types of objects.

Comment: @Adam tie(x,y) = make_pair(1,2); actually becomes std::tie(x, y).operator=(std::make_pair(1, 2)), it's why "assignment to an rvalue" works XD

Answer (score 61):

This does not answer your question in any way, but let me post it anyway because C++17 is basically ready (with compiler support), so while wondering how the outdated stuff works, it is probably worth looking at how the current, and future, version of C++ works, too.

With C++17 you can pretty much scratch `std::tie` in favour of what is called *structured bindings*. They do the same (well, *not the same*, but they have the same net effect), although you need to type fewer characters, it does not need library support, and you *also* have the ability to take references, if that happens to be what you want.

(Note that in C++17 constructors do argument deduction, so `make_tuple` has become somewhat superfluous, too.)

```
int a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(2, 3);

// C++17
auto  [c, d] = std::make_tuple(4, 5);
auto  [e, f] = std::tuple(6, 7);
std::tuple t(8,9); auto& [g, h] = t; // not possible with std::tie
```

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that unlike `tie`, structured bindings can be used this way on types that aren't default-constructible.

Comment: Yeah, `std::tie()` is a lot less useful since C++17, where structured bindings are usually superior, but it still has uses, including assigning to existing (not simultaneously newly declared) variables and concisely doing other things like swapping multiple variables or other things that must assign to references.

Comment: Structured bindings can't be compared.  Ties can.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I can now say good bye to std::get<int>(...) calls forever! The call syntax is just so unnecessarily cumbersome. Who suggested it?