# When using custom class in std::map with custom comparator -> error: static assertion failed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, stdmap

Hello to *everyone* who will find this post helpful. I had this custom class `Position` and I wanted to use it in `std::map`

```cpp
class Position
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Position(const int &pos_x, const int &pos_y)
        : x(pos_x), y(pos_y) {}
};
```

But i had error because it couldn't compare the classes to each other. So I created this comparison class:

```cpp
class PosComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const ConsoleRenderer::Position &A, const ConsoleRenderer::Position &B)
    {
        if (A.x < B.x)
            return true;
        else if (A.x == B.x && A.y < B.y)
            return true;
        return false;
     }
};
```

But I got this this error:

> static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const

Comment: Shorter: `return std::tie(A.x, A.y) < std::tie(B.x, B.y);`

Answer (score 1):

As the error implied, adding `const` at the end solves the problem:

```
class PosComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const ConsoleRenderer::Position &A, const ConsoleRenderer::Position &B) const
    {
        if (A.x < B.x)
            return true;
        else if (A.x == B.x && A.y < B.y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Or make it shorter by using [`std::tie`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762651/how-does-stdtie-work), creating tuples which can be use to [compare](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/operators/):

```
class PosComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const ConsoleRenderer::Position &A, const ConsoleRenderer::Position &B) const
    {
        return std::tie(A.x, A.y) < std::tie(B.x, B.y);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with **simply** adding `const` at the end of the line.

```cpp
class PosComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const ConsoleRenderer::Position &A, const ConsoleRenderer::Position &B) const
    {
        if (A.x < B.x)
            return true;
        else if (A.x == B.x && A.y < B.y)
            return true;
        return false;
     }
};
```

**Hopefully this helped. :)**

Comment: you might simplify implementation to `return std::tie(A.x, A.y) < std::tie(B.x, B.y);`.