# Partial Constructor arguments from tuple

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, stdtuple

In C++17 there's [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple); However that only applies to situations where the number of the elements stored in the tuple matches with that of the constructor.

I was able to concatenate two tuples and use `std::make_from_tuple`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

class ConstructMe{
public:
  ConstructMe(int a_, int b_, int c_)
  : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) { }

private:
  int a;
  int b, c;
};

int main(){
  int a = 1;
  std::tuple<int, int> part = std::make_tuple(2,3);
  ConstructMe please = std::make_from_tuple<ConstructMe>(
    std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(a), part)
  );
  return 0;
}
```

And after some research ( [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762651/how-does-stdtie-work) I was able to make it work with references as well with [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

class ConstructMe{
public:
  ConstructMe(int& a_, int b_, int c_)
  : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) { }

private:
  int& a;
  int b, c;
};

int main(){
  int a = 1;
  std::tuple<int, int> part = std::make_tuple(2,3);
  ConstructMe please = std::make_from_tuple<ConstructMe>(
    std::tuple_cat(std::tie(a), part)
  );
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this ( e.g. with [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) which doesn't require c++17?

Comment: If you tag the question C++17 it's about realizing something in C++17. But it seems you want to realize it in an older version: tag it the version you are using. `std::tie` was already in C++14. Many of the tuple stuff you mention since C++11.

Comment: `std::make_from_tuple` is a c++17 feature

Comment: It's not clear form the question that you are only talking about `make_form_tuple`, and still: you want to realize it in another version. So tag which version you want. By the way as `make_from_tuple` is a library feature, not a language feature, you can always make your own implementation of it, based on the standardized one.

Comment: I removed the c++17 tag as per your suggestion, because this is not something I'd like to realize in c++17. However I would not like to pin an exact standard to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bind` does something completely different. Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

> The function template `bind` generates a forwarding call wrapper for `f`. Calling this wrapper is equivalent to invoking `f` with some of its arguments bound to `args`.

You can just use the cpp reference link to build your own implementation of the standardized function, e.g. in C++14

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
template <class T, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr T make_from_tuple_impl( Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...> )
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible<T,
        decltype(std::get<I>(std::declval<Tuple>()))...>::value);
    return T(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
} // namespace detail
 
template <class T, class Tuple>
constexpr T make_from_tuple( Tuple&& t )
{
    return detail::make_from_tuple_impl<T>(std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}

class ConstructMe{
public:
  ConstructMe(int& a_, int b_, int c_)
  : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) { }

private:
  int& a;
  int b, c;
};

int main(){
  int a = 1;
  std::tuple<int, int> part = std::make_tuple(2,3);
  ConstructMe please = make_from_tuple<ConstructMe>(
    std::tuple_cat(std::tie(a), part)
  );
}
```

If you want to go back more language versions, you have to do more by hand. It will be harder and harder, especially if you want to go before C++11...

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Seems there's no black magic to it, and the implementation is part of the standard for a good reason.